# How to set string property value to the ComboBox control inside Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` in my WPF project. The model which I am binding has property `DataType` of type `string`. In normal display mode I am displaying it like:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource CellBlock}" Text="{Binding DataType}" ToolTip="{Binding DataType}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

In edit mode I need to populate an `enum` in the `ComboBox` and set the selected combo box item to the item which is coming from `string` model property `Datatype` and if user changes the value in combobox it should get reflected in model.
How can I achieve these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a custom cell template for that, `DataGrid` has a built-in `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. In normal mode, it displays the value as text and in edit-mode it shows a `ComboBox`.

You have to expose the constants that your `enum` defines as a collection. You can create a simple `MarkupExtension` for that that returns the values of  any given `enum` type.

```
public class EnumValuesExtension : MarkupExtension
{
   public Type Type { get; set; }

   public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
      return Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
   }
}
```

This is an example of your `DataGrid`. As you can see, you can simply use the markup extension to bind the `ItemsSource` of the combo box column to your `enum` type, which is `MyEnum` here.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding newItems}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{local:EnumValues Type={x:Type local:MyEnum}}"
                              SelectedItemBinding="{Binding DataType}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In your model, use the `enum` type for the `DataType` property. I do not think there is any use in exposing it as `string`. The example above assumes that you use your `enum` type, not `string`.

However, if you really depend on it being a `string`, you can create a simple [value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data).

```
public class StringToEnumConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return Enum.Parse((Type)parameter, (string)value);
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return value.ToString();
   }
}
```

This would change the binding on the combo box column to this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{local:EnumValues Type={x:Type local:MyEnum}}"
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding DataType, Converter={StaticResource StringToEnumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Type local:MyEnum}}"/>
```

Comment: Where to specify the property binding("Datatype") in second approach?

Comment: @AmolShinde There was a typo. I corrected it, it is also `SelectedItemBinding`.